# Symfony 1.4 - Do something before checking credentials

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have some credential requirements for my modules in security.yml.
How can i run a method before this checking is done? Is there any events for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Filters](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_1/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters) might be what you need.
Filters are run first every time your application runs.

Just add a filter in the *apps/(front|back)end/config/filters.yml* file:

```
myFilter:
  class: myFilter
```

And create the class in *lib/*:

```
class myFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute($filterChain)
  {
    // write your code here...

    // execute the next filter
    $filterChain->execute();
  }
}
```